# jquery ajax async is not working accordingly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

This is my javascript code:

```
function getData(param1,param2) {
    $.ajaxSetup({async:false});
    var request = $.ajax({
        url: "http://someurl.com/xyz.php?p1="+param1+"&p2="+param2,
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        success: function(imageurl){
            return imageurl;
        }
    });
}
```

and here is the PHP page in which, I am calling this function:

```
<html>
<head>
     <script src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script src="http://myjsdomain.com/myjs.js"></script>
        <script>

            function callMyFunction(box) {
                alert(box);
                box.value = "Waiting....";
                var data = getData('param1', 'param2'); 
                box.value = data;
                alert(data);    //here I am getting "Undefined"
            }
        </script>
</head>
<body>
        <?=$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]?><br />
        <input type="button" onclick="callMyFunction(this)" value="Click Here" />
</body>
</html>
```

Now When I am calling this `getData()` function in My php page then it returns `"Undefined"`.

When I alert data in JavaScript code ,it alerts correct value but still `"undefined"` in PHP page.

It is an Ajax ASYNC problem but even after setting it `false` , I am still facing this problem.

I debugged it with firebug and I can see that the URL (from where I am getting the data using ajax) is returning correct value but it is not receiving on PHP page where I am calling this function.

Any suggestions to make this work

Comment: Change `POST` to `GET` since you're passing your data in the url.

Comment: From the docs -  As of jQuery 1.8, the use of async: false with jqXHR ($.Deferred) is deprecated; you must use the success/error/complete callback options instead of the corresponding methods of the jqXHR object such as jqXHR.done() or the deprecated jqXHR.success().

Comment: @JayBlanchard can you provide the code by using done?

Comment: Is the `getData()` function also on the PHP page, or included through a file anywhere? From that `Undefined` error it seems not.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Comment: @Styphon it is in separate file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to return result from function `getData`, return in `success` function is not enough - it's in diferent scope

```
function getData(param1,param2) {
  var result;
  var request = $.ajax({
    url: "http://someurl.com/xyz.php?p1="+param1+"&p2="+param2,
    type: "GET",
    async: false,
    success: function(imageurl){
      result = imageurl;
    }
  });
  return result;
}
```

Or you can do it asynchronously this way:

```
function changeValue(box, param1, param2) {
  box.value = "Waiting....";
  var request = $.ajax({
    url: "http://someurl.com/xyz.php?p1="+param1+"&p2="+param2,
    type: "GET",
    async: true,
    success: function(imageurl){
      box.value = imageurl;
    }
  });
  return result;
}
function callMyFunction(box) {
  alert(box);
  changeValue(box, 'param1', 'param2')
}
```

Comment: You need to change the type. It's a `GET`, not a `POST`.

Comment: Don't use `async:false`!

Comment: @Bergi what should I use to make async:flase?

Comment: @Despicable: See my answer, the code didn't fit well into a comment

Answer (score 2):

Just as an alternative to the accepted answer, here's how to do it properly in an asynchronous way with promises. See the duplicate question [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call) for more explanation.

```
function getData(param1, param2) {
    return $.ajax({
        url: "http://someurl.com/xyz.php",
        data: {p1:param1, p2:param2},
        type: "GET" // I think this is fine since you didn't send any data
    });
}
function callMyFunction(box) {
    alert(box);
    box.value = "Waiting....";
    getData('param1', 'param2').then(function(imageurl) { 
        box.value = imageurl;
        alert(imageurl);
    });
}
```

Comment: ***Promises*** is stable ?

Comment: @Kiquenet: Sure they are. And even when they are not natively available in some browsers, there are many libraries that implement them. Even jQuery comes with deferreds (which are used in this answer here).